# Execute shell command in python

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I had been trying to execute openshift command in python. 
I have something like this that I need to try from python.

```
oc get quota --all-namespaces -o template --template="\
status.used.limits.cpu ,\
status.used.limits.memory,\
spec.hard.limits.cpu,\
spec.hard.limits.memory,\
{{-  println -}}
{{range .items }}\
{{ .kind }},{{ .metadata.namespace }},\
{{ -1 | (index .status.used \"limits.cpu\" ) }},\
{{ -1 | (index .status.used \"limits.memory\" ) }},\
{{ -1 | (index .spec.hard \"limits.cpu\" ) }},\
{{ -1 | (index .spec.hard \"limits.memory\" ) }},\
{{- println -}}{{end}}" | column -t -s ','
```

Now I try to use subprocess call and tried something like below

```
       cmd = ['oc get quota --all-namespaces -o template --template=status.used.limits.cpu ,'
       'status.used.limits.memory,spec.hard.limits.cpu,spec.hard.limits.memory,{{-  println -}}{{range .items }}'
       '{{ .kind }},{{ .metadata.namespace }},{{ -1 | (index .status.used \"limits.cpu\" ) }},'
       '{{ -1 | (index .status.used \"limits.memory\" ) }},{{ -1 | (index .spec.hard \"limits.cpu\" ) }},'
       '{{ -1 | (index .spec.hard \"limits.memory\" ) }},{{- println -}}{{end}} | column -t -s ,'
]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output,err = p.communicate()
print(output)
```

And I got error `OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long`
Do I need to have this command in a file and read it? I don't know how that would work. Also, do I need to put every word in `cmd` in quotes?

Comment: Did you forget about in list? (After single quote)

Comment: Your shell command includes a `|` pipe, which is a shell feature. Yet you are not running your command through a shell anymore (`shell=False` is the default). You'll also need to do your own argument splitting, and the quotes around `--template="..."` need to go, those the shell would have parsed. Or pass in  a single string and set `shell=True`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, please check my edit. I added shell=True and removed quotes. However, output is blank.

Comment: @HeenashreeKhandelwal: you misunderstood me. If you add `shell=True`, **do not remove the quotes**, because now the shell is still going to parse those. You *do* need to remove the `[...]` list from your around your string.